# Monkey can take either 2 or 3 steps - how many different ways to reach the top?

Tags: c#, algorithm, dynamic-programming

So basically I'm trying to solve this problem both recursively and dynamically.
The problem sounds like this: There're stairs with "n" steps how many different ways can the monkey reach the top if she can only jump over either 1 step or 2 steps (she can't just jump on the next step).

Lets say we have stairs with 4 steps - there's only one way 2-2 = 1 way (if she tried jumping over 3 - she couldn't just step on the next one to reach the top).

5 steps could be: 2-3 and 3-2 = 2 ways. (we can say "over 1 step jump" = 2 steps. "over 2 step jump" = 3 steps)

So this sounds similiar to the usual "can take either 1 or 2 steps, how many ways?" problem, but because have "2 or 3 steps" - somehow it got for me confusing.

My solution recursively looks like this:

```
        static int F1(int n, int ways)
    {
        if (n < 0) return 0;
        if (n > 0) return F1(n - 2, ways) + F1(n - 3, ways);
        else
        {
            if (n == 0) ways++;
            return ways;
        }
    }
```

But I have no idea how to do this dynamically even after looking at similiar problem with 1 and 2 steps. What's different here ? Would appreciate some kind of help or if someone has something like this solved.

Comment: And what if `n < 0` ?

Comment: This is *already* a "dynamic" solution (correct phrase is *dynamic programming*) - it computes the solution to a problem based on solutions to sub-problems (although not correctly yet).

Comment: @HenkHolterman edited, thanks for noticing - if the edit is correct ofc.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog what I mean by dynamic approach is something like: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/ at the "Dynamic Programming Solution" or am I understanding this incorrect? - So what I wrote isn't considered recursive approach ?

Comment: An algorithm can be both DP and recursive; in-fact, recursion is often the most natural way to implement a DP approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different version. No reason to pass `ways` as input, `steps` is for diagnostics:

```
static int F1(int n, string steps)
{                        
    if (n == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(steps);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n > 0)
    {
        return F1(n - 3, steps + "3") + F1(n - 2, steps + "2");
    }

    // else: no dice, invalid outcome
    return 0;            
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a better implementation - do you have an idea how it could look using dynamic approach?

Comment: Like others commented, I don't see the non-dynamic here.